# How to use bitmap to load any image format in wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

```
import wx
import sys, glob

class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
 def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,"wx.ListCtrl in wx.LC_ICON mode",size=(600,400))
    il_max=0
    il = wx.ImageList(200,200)
    for name in glob.glob("img/*.bmp"):
        bmp = wx.Bitmap(name, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)

        il_max = il.Add(bmp)

    self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_ICON | wx.LC_AUTOARRANGE)

    self.list.AssignImageList(il, wx.IMAGE_LIST_NORMAL)

    for x in range(25):
        img = x % (il_max+1)
        self.list.InsertImageStringItem(x, "This is item %02d" % x, img)

 app = wx.PySimpleApp()
 frame = DemoFrame()
 frame.Show()
 app.MainLoop()
```

This code only work with bmp not with jpeg or png

What suitable change is required to get it work with any image format?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
bmp = wx.Bitmap(name, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
```

to

```
bmp = wx.Bitmap(name, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
```

There's also

```
BITMAP_TYPE_CUR
BITMAP_TYPE_ICON
BITMAP_TYPE_IFF
BITMAP_TYPE_GIF
BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG
BITMAP_TYPE_PNG
BITMAP_TYPE_TIF
```

....among others

Comment: Or just `bmp = wx.Bitmap(name)` as `..._ANY` is the default.